# How do you set inner spacing in a collection view cell with 2 cells per row?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, collectionview

Ive been stuck on this for two weeks now. Searched everywhere and still can't find a solution. I want to bring the cells closer to the middle. Also have another collection view with 3 cells per row I need to do the same thing with. Thanks

[image]

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

return CGSize(width: 153, height: 241)

}

//

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 11, 10, 11)

}

//

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

return 0

}

//

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout    collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, maximumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

return 0

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jusr read comment     , don't forget to setup your cell  at               `let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell`

```
 extension ViewController :UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UICollectionViewDataSource{
         func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 100 // data source
          }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

              let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
               cell.backgroundColor = .red
              return cell
           }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

            // 3 cell same size in each row space between them 4
            let spaceBetweenCell :CGFloat = 4.0  // if you change this parmters you have to change minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt ,
            let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - CGFloat(2 * spaceBetweenCell)
            let totalSpace = spaceBetweenCell * 2.0;  // there is 2 between  3 item
            return CGSize(width: (screenWidth - totalSpace)/3, height: (screenWidth-totalSpace)/3)

        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 4.0 // space between sections
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 4.0 // space between items in row
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy with your cell sizes and just want to move them closer, then adjust your `left` and `right` insets (which are the 2nd and 4th inputs to `UIEdgeInsetsMake`):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 16, 10, 16)
}
```